# How to Get the list of recently replicated/added records in the Subscriber database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-replication

We have a primary Database(Publisher) which is replicated into a secondary database(Subscriber - not updatable) in another SQL server instance. Both are SQL server 2012 instance and replication is Transactional. The secondary database is used only by the reporting team.

Let's say we are having a main table and two more child tables that are being replicated. Now in Secondary database, We are planning to have a queue which should contain the recently replicated records as soon as it enters the secondary database. This is to let the reporting applications know about the new records to be processed. I need the primary key from our main table to go into this queue. Is there any system objects which i can make use of.

For example:

In Primary Database:

```
Insert into table1(Id,Name) values(5,'abc')
Insert into table1(Id,Name) values(6,'xyz')
```

Once these two records reach the secondary Database, I want the Ids '5' and '6' to be inserted into that queue. The Queue can be a just another table.

Note: I have an idea to filter out records based on CRUD date but again we need something to trigger this stored procedure as soon as new records enter(rather than a scheduled job). But I feel there must be a smarter way than this.

Comment: Consider a trigger on inserts in the subscriber, inserting newly added keys in a queue table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @TT . That would solve the problem for new inserts. But in case of any updates, I will be forced to keep a trigger in all the child tables to identify the corresponding parent that was updated. But we don't like to have those many triggers.